# How to implement digitally reconstructed radiograph (DRR) in python

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, itk, medical

Looking for reference code, preferably in python for generating an XRAY from CT.

This should model as much of the following factors:

- Attenuation (LUT)
- Focal point
- XRay beam shape and angle
- XRay energy (keV)

I am already familiar with the following options and looking for something better then:

1. `volume.sum(1)` (assuming `volume` is a numpy 3d array)
2. [MeVisLab](https://mevislabdownloads.mevis.de/docs/2.3/MeVisLab/Standard/Documentation/Publish/ModuleReference/CArmDRR.html) supports what I'm looking for but does not allow for simple python integration without installing all of the > 1 GB software.
3. VTK has some examples ([1](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Volume/Testing/Python/TestGPURayCastIndependentComponentMIP.py), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20170330235405/https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/65373/vtk.vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper)) but they don't show working with LUT for simulating attenuation.
4. There's [this](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/Examples_2Filtering_2DigitallyReconstructedRadiograph1_8cxx-example.html) ITK example, but its in c++ and I suspect that it too works using mean intensity projection rather then simulating attenuation.